# How to find the series $a_{n}$ which has this generating function: $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, generating-functions

I'm given a generating function $f(x)$:
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}
$$
Naturally, I tried to transform it into the form $f(x)=\sum_0^\infty a_n \cdot x^n$.

So far I figured out what follows:
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1+x)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-x} + \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1+x}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n+\frac{1}{1-(-x)} \right)
$$$$
\frac{1}{1-(-x)}=1+(-x)+x^2+(-x^3)+x^4+\cdots
$$$$
\frac{1}{1-(-x)}=(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots)-(x+x^3+x^5+\cdots)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}-x^{2n+1}
$$
Therefore:
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n+x^{2n}-x^{2n+1} \right)
$$
Now I am lost. Is my train of thought good? Am I anywhere near finding the series which is generated by function $f(x)$?

Comment: Undoubtedly you have seen
$$\frac1{1-q}=1+q+q^2+q^3+\cdots.$$ Plug in $q=x^2$ and be done with it.

Comment: You are almost there. To finish just observe that $$\left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n+x^{2n}-x^{2n+1} \right)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}+x^{2n+1}$$

Comment: $\begin{aligned} \frac{1}{1-x} \cdot\frac{1}{1+x} & = \bigg(\sum_{k \ge 0}x^k \bigg) \bigg(\sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k x^k\bigg) \\& = \sum_{n \ge 0}\sum_{0 \le k \le n}x^k (-1)^{n-k}x^{n-k} \\& = \displaystyle \sum_{n \ge 0}(-1)^n x^n \sum_{0 \le k \le n} (-1)^{k} \\&= \sum_{n \ge 0}(-1)^n x^n \cdot \frac{1 + (-1)^n}{2} \\& =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1+(-1)^n}{2} x^n \end{aligned}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To repair the approach you were taking:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^2} = \frac{1/2}{1-x} + \frac{1/2}{1+x} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1+(-1)^n}{2} x^n,
$$
so
$$
a_n = \frac{1+(-1)^n}{2} = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if $2\mid n$} \\0 &\text{otherwise}\\ \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 3):

$\frac 1 {1-x^2}=1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots$ for $|x| <1$ since $\frac 1 {1-r}=1+r+r^2+\cdots$ for $|r|<1$. So $a_n=1$ for $n$ even and $a_n=0$ for $n$ odd.